# Linux pxe boot is successes, but how do I make it muti OS (7.1 and 7.2) for each MAC?

Tags: linux, pxe-boot

I did a setup a pxe boot recently and it’s works like a charm without any issues, so the phase 1 is okay and success.
Now the question is, I have two client with mac address and how to configure a profile for each?

At present whatever system (client) boot from network the installation will happen with default (current) setup
How do I make differentiate with MAC address for each host? Say for system1 7.1 and for system 7.2 to be installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a file for a part (or whole) of the mac address.

Have a look here:
http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=PXELINUX#Configuration